# Cropper.js only enable zoom

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

Is it possible to disable all cropper functionality and only enable `cropper.zoom()` for example?

If I disable cropper with `cropper.disable()` it disables everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code it’s seems that this option isn’t supported:

```
  // Disable (freeze) the cropper
  disable() {
    if (this.ready && !this.disabled) {
      this.disabled = true;
      addClass(this.cropper, CLASS_DISABLED);
    }

    return this;
  },
```

Source:
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/89f0b50c7f580135582a087cbf2417126b67d5fd/src/js/methods.js#L137

You can open an issue or do it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it is by setting these options like this:

```
autoCrop: false,
dragMode: 'move
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration might help:

```
config: any = {
    dragMode: 'none',
    highlight: false,
    modal: false,
    responsive: true,
    scalable: true,
    autoCrop: false,
    center: false,
    background: false,
    zoomable: true,
    zoomOnWheel: true,
};
```